# OpenID, Facebook Connect and Twitter OAuth in ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, openid, coldfusion-9

Can someone help me in implementing OpenID, Facebook Connect and Twitter OAuth in a ColdFusion 9 application as single signon. I have checked ColdFusion-based OpenID script on [RiaForge](http://riaforge.org) and lost in the middle to store returning authenticated data into the database. I could not find good tutorials regarding this. If some can guide me a way, it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The ColdFusion Meetup group has a presentation about this recently:

"CFMeetup: Authentication made easy using Twitter/Facebook/Google/more"

http://experts.adobeconnect.com/p6wit9dnz39/

Charlie Arehart maintains a large list of CF presentations here: http://www.carehart.org/ugtv/

Comment: Yah, I think he's going to be speaking at NCDevCon too.